# String Replace that contains hashtags-php

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I have a string like this

$content="#Love #Lovestories #Lovewalapyar";

Want to make these hashtags clickable.

I have an array.

```
$tags=
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TOPIC_ID] => 132
            [TOPIC_NAME] => Love
            [TOPIC_URL] => http://local/topic/132/love            
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TOPIC_ID] => 3347
            [TOPIC_NAME] => LoveStories
            [TOPIC_URL] => http://local/topic/3347/lovestories            
        )

  
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TOPIC_ID] => 43447
            [TOPIC_NAME] => lovewalapyar
            [TOPIC_URL] => http://local/topic/43447/lovewalapyar            
        )

);

Using this to make hashtags clickable.

foreach($tags as $tag){
    $content=str_ireplace('#'.$tag->TOPIC_NAME, '<a href="'.$tag->TOPIC_URL.'" title="'.htmlentities($tag->TOPIC_NAME).'">#'.$tag->TOPIC_NAME.'</a>', $content);
}
```

[image: It prints like this]

Getting this:
It replaces only love not the other string.

Trying to replace/Make these hashtags clickable.

Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple. You have hashtags which are substrings of other hashtags.
To avoid this overlapping issue, you can sort your array in a non-increasing fashion replacing longer strings first and shorter strings later, completely avoid the overlapping issue, like below:

```
<?php

usort($tags,function($a,$b){
   return strlen($b->TOPIC_NAME) <=> strlen($a->TOPIC_NAME);
});
```

**Update:**

Your hashtag text inside `<a></a>` is causing the `str_ireplace` to reconsider it. For this you need to pass the array values and their respective replacements in an array, or,  instead of adding a `#`, you can use a HTML character entity `&#35;` which will be ignored by `str_ireplace()` and would work properly, like below:

```
'<a ...>&#35;'.$tag->TOPIC_NAME.'</a>';
```

**Updated Snippet:**

```
<?php

usort($tags,function($a,$b){
   return strlen($b->TOPIC_NAME) <=> strlen($a->TOPIC_NAME);
});

foreach($tags as $tag){
    $content = str_ireplace('#'.$tag->TOPIC_NAME, '<a href="'.$tag->TOPIC_URL.'" title="'.htmlentities($tag->TOPIC_NAME).'">&#35;'. $tag->TOPIC_NAME.'</a>', $content);
}
```

Comment: Dear @nice_dev, I had tried multiple logic. But It worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @SurajAnand Glad it worked perfectly. If you don't mind, can you mark it as accepted? By this, future researchers would know that this is a working solution.

Comment: Sure, @nice_dev

Answer (score 1):

I would use the regular expression `/#(\w*)/` (hashtag and whitespace) and `preg_replace()` to replace all occurrences.

Something like this:

```php
$content = "#Love #Lovestories #Lovewalapyar";
$pattern = '/#(\w*)/';
$replacement = '<a href="#$1">$1</a>';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

this  will give you:

```html
<a href="#Love">Love</a> 
<a href="#Lovestories">Lovestories</a> 
<a href="#Lovewalapyar">Lovewalapyar</a>
```

You can test that [regex online here](https://regex101.com/r/ZKapWU/1).

---

If you need some advanced logic as *Magnus Eriksson* mentioned in comments you can use `preg_match_all` and iterate over your found matches.

Something like this:

```php
$content = "#Love #Lovestories #Lovewalapyar";
$pattern = '/#(\w*)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $match) {
    // do whatever you need here, you might want to use $tag = $tags[$key];
}
```

Comment: It's not that straightforward though, since the URL's they want to replace them with are specific for each tag (including different id's) and not just `href="#tagname"`. This doesn't give them the result they want.